# passively eavesdrops and then impersonate

Tags: encryption, hash

Alice and Bob have a shared symmetric key k ∈ {0, 1}^256, which Alice
uses to identify herself to Bob, who holds a database of usernames and
shared keys. The identification protocol they use begins when Alice
sends her username, Bob responds with a challenge c ∈ {0, 1}^256, and
Alice chooses a response r ∈ {0, 1}^∗ and returns the pair <h(k||r||c),r>,
such that h is a collision-resistant hash function with the Merkle Damgard design, and || denotes concatenation.

(a) Show how Eve who passively eavesdrops on the connection between Alice and Bob can impersonate Alice.

(b) Is this attack still possible if h is defined by the sponge design?
Justify your answer.

Comment: Hint: explore the [tag:length-extension] property of the Merkle–Damgård construction. Question (a) could be: Show how Eve who has passively eavesdropped on the connection between Alice and Bob can then impersonate Alice.